# Pass API errors through Azure Functions Proxy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I've got an Azure Functions Proxy set up that calls an underlying API. This is working fine, but there seems to be some inconsistent behaviour when it comes to passing errors from the API.

When trying to get a resource that doesn't exist the API returns a 404 response with a friendly error message. This gets passed through the proxy as well, so the caller gets to see that message.

When a server error happens the API returns a 500 response with a friendly error message, but in this case that response does not get passed through the proxy and instead it returns a generic XML error:

```
<ApiErrorModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Models">
  <Arguments xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails i:nil="true" />
  <Id>edf8c2a7-cb2e-45a0-b2c7-f5ef849c9f50</Id>
  <Message>An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID edf8c2a7-cb2e-45a0-b2c7-f5ef849c9f50</Message>
  <RequestId i:nil="true" />
  <StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
</ApiErrorModel>
```

Is there a way to get the proxy to pass through any error messages it receives from the API back to the calling client?

Comment: Generally the response is initialized as a copy of the API response, so what you want seems not blocked. The generic error shows when we directly trigger a azure function with unhandled exception inside(no proxy set).  Could you describe `a server error happens` in detail?

Comment: @JerryLiu Thinking about it, it might be the proxy throwing the error. So the scenario I have here is if the API URL gets called with an invalid parameter value: `https://myapi.com/method?param=<test`. This would normally throw an `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client` error. Could it be that the proxy is doing the same before it calls the backend API?

Comment: You can always add the Proxy-Trace-Enabled: true header to your request to see where in the pipeline the error is coming from.

Comment: @HenryHamidSafi-MSFT The debug tip was useful. I found that it behaves differently depending on the URL you feed it:
`https://myapi.com/method?param=<test` gives back the right response (since the querystring gets encoded).
But `https://myapi.com/another-method/<test` still gives the error message I originally posted. And in that case I don't get a trace log entry either?

Comment: Yes most likely the function runtime will return 500 before it's sent to backend. try to add this appsetting as well to see if behavior changes: AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_BACKEND_URL_DECODE_SLASHES: true

Comment: @HenryHamidSafi-MSFT No, unfortunately that didn't make a difference.